# Unable to create application: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build an React Native app that I created at 2020. I completely run the IOS device but I face an error with Android. When I install to device and open, I faced the error I mentioned title.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.app.MainApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Requested enabled DevSupportManager, but BridgeDevSupportManager class was not found or could not be created
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7053)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:254)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:233)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

How can I solve it to start the app that crashes right now when it opens?

Additional informations

React
"react": "16.14",
"react-native": "0.62.0"

Android

```
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    androidXCore = "1.5.0"
    kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

Comment: same issue . was running fine yesterday. today i updated some packages and now it not wokring

Answer (score -3):

Add below line in android app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I can confirm that this solution is not working. Tried also version 4.9.3 and it doesn't work!